# Finding middle points between two lines of figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinate-systems

I have a figure in the coordinates system that you can see here:

[image: picture Here]

As you can see it consists of 2 mostly parallel lines, what I want is to make, instead of two lines, just one line that goes through middle of those 2 lines, for example:

[image: here is what I mean]

Just note I did this manually so it doesn't look like the original picture, but you should get the point.

Here is the code I am using for plotting:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

A = 155, 158, 182, 186, 195, 256, 263, 275, 284, 317, 317, 317, 316, 316, 312, 310, 305, 295, 296, 300, 294, 288, 280, 266, 251, 194, 189, 188, 187, 183, 142, 126, 101, 101, 101, 131, 189, 232, 290, 306, 309, 309, 309, 288, 266, 227, 218, 214, 208, 175, 156, 134, 89 , 79 , 72 , 58 , 57 , 56 , 69 , 87 , 132, 154, 167, 196, 234, 252, 260, 274, 281, 281, 281, 233, 201, 176, 132, 110, 90 , 74 , 74 , 74 , 75 , 75 , 77 , 94 , 108, 151
B = 475, 475, 492, 492, 492, 519, 521, 524, 524, 524, 495, 494, 488, 487, 471, 471, 471, 484, 488, 492, 496, 499, 499, 499, 492, 467, 467, 467, 467, 467, 436, 420, 397, 387, 375, 360, 329, 284, 224, 178, 170, 163, 142, 132, 122, 122, 122, 124, 128, 133, 136, 136, 136, 126, 119, 124, 134, 146, 152, 161, 161, 161, 158, 151, 151, 151, 152, 153, 158, 165, 178, 248, 283, 308, 329, 340, 358, 374, 381, 382, 386, 388, 400, 421, 437, 475


plt.plot(A, B)
for xy in zip(A, B):
    ax.annotate('(%s, %s)' % xy, xy=xy, textcoords='data')  # <--

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is the data structure fixed? It would be much better if the coordinates can be a set of points. And the track has a starting poing

Comment: Is this what you are thinking? For every point i have x,y, for example like this 155,475 , all is one line, it's not i get coordinate for x,y and then the same coordinate on second line

Answer (score 1):

Not the perfect solution but you can get a good approximation using a Nearest Neighbors algorithm (the best option would be using dijkstra distance or other hierarchical clustering procedures but I am not sure how much level of detail you need).

Here is a simple implementation using `KMeans`

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

A = 155, 158, 182, 186, 195, 256, 263, 275, 284, 317, 317, 317, 316, 316, 312, 310, 305, 295, 296, 300, 294, 288, 280, 266, 251, 194, 189, 188, 187, 183, 142, 126, 101, 101, 101, 131, 189, 232, 290, 306, 309, 309, 309, 288, 266, 227, 218, 214, 208, 175, 156, 134, 89 , 79 , 72 , 58 , 57 , 56 , 69 , 87 , 132, 154, 167, 196, 234, 252, 260, 274, 281, 281, 281, 233, 201, 176, 132, 110, 90 , 74 , 74 , 74 , 75 , 75 , 77 , 94 , 108, 151
B = 475, 475, 492, 492, 492, 519, 521, 524, 524, 524, 495, 494, 488, 487, 471, 471, 471, 484, 488, 492, 496, 499, 499, 499, 492, 467, 467, 467, 467, 467, 436, 420, 397, 387, 375, 360, 329, 284, 224, 178, 170, 163, 142, 132, 122, 122, 122, 124, 128, 133, 136, 136, 136, 126, 119, 124, 134, 146, 152, 161, 161, 161, 158, 151, 151, 151, 152, 153, 158, 165, 178, 248, 283, 308, 329, 340, 358, 374, 381, 382, 386, 388, 400, 421, 437, 475

df=pd.DataFrame([list(A),list(B)]).T
df.columns=['A','B']

km = KMeans(n_clusters=20).fit(df)
pts=km.cluster_centers_[km.labels_]
```

Here is the output:

[image: kmeans]

```
plt.plot(pts[:,0],pts[:,1])
plt.plot(X, Y)
```

Here are the centroids:

```
plt.plot(km.cluster_centers_[:,0], km.cluster_centers_[:,1],'.')
plt.plot(X, Y)
```

[image: centroids]

You need to play around with the number of clusters but you can get pretty accurate approximations. Here is with 12 centroids:

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters=12).fit(df)
pts=km.cluster_centers_[km.labels_]
plt.plot(pts[:,0], pts[:,1])
plt.plot(X, Y)
```

[image: 12centroids]

Comment: I would like to get more details, the more precision(details) i get it's better. Can you show an implementation with dijkstra distance or other hierarchical clustering?